# Data structure for a search engine?

Tags: data-structures, search-engine

Which is the most efficient data structure or algorithm, which can be used for storing search engine data. Also which distributed file system could go with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Inverted Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)**

For more details refer open source Lucene and Nutch architecture.

Answer (score 2):

[Ternary Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_tree)

I think that it's the best.